# Select one column, group by another - ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Tags: mysql, laravel, select, group-by, strict

I have this data

```
1 => blue,
2 => red,
3 => red
```

All I want is:

```
[1, 2]
```

With MySql strict mode disabled, or more specifically, ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled - i can do

```
SELECT id ... GROUP BY color
```

But with it enabled I cannot do that and doing

```
SELECT color, id ... GROUP BY color, id
```

produces the same result as what I started with

Any help other than disabling strict mode and/or ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY 
Or perhaps I should just disable those. It seems to be causing more harm than good

Comment: _"It seems to be causing more harm than good"_ - on the contrary, it prevents you from getting [1, 3] as a result, which you _don't_ want, but would be just as likely to get otherwise. (Because that there's _any_ difference between those two rows with color red, that's just your imagination.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're grouping by `color`, but not specifying what you want to do with `id` in the event there is a many-to-one relationship.

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(id) as id ... GROUP BY color
```

This line now says "group by color, and select the smallest `id` for each.", whereas previously it found two records of "red" and had no idea how to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

then you mean that you want indicate the all the column you are using for aggregation in group by   so if you are selecting col1,col2,col3  you must set col1,col2,col3  in group by .. if you don't need 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' this not happen but the row selected in aggreegation are impredictable .. see this tutorial  for sample  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/counting-rows.html

In your case you are not using aggreagtion function like count or min or max so seems you don't need group by ..

for getting only the row 1 and 2 you should simply use  a filter like

```
select   color, id  from my_table where id<> 3;
```